# Opera ≤11.5 Breaks Orbit slider image Centering

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, opera, orbit

I've been attempting to incorporate the zurb foundation Orbit slider into a pre-existing site homepage that has a number of linked (and locked/read-only) stylesheets.  As you can imagine this has caused many many browser compatibility issues to arise but I thought the other day that I finally had it working!

However, I found that versions of Opera before 11.6 cause the slider to display particularly wonkily... Even on a blank page with only the slider, the slides seem to just start from the wrong position.  So for example, slide #1 will show most of the 1st image (minus the far-left side) and also the beginning left portion of the 2nd image.

I created a page at jsBin to demonstrate the issue.  http://jsbin.com/aqejil/5/
Note that you can edit the code on jsBin with the button in the top-right.  In the CSS editing tab I also included a code snippet that should target the different slider elements in only Opera 11:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){}
.orbit-container {}
.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container {}
.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container img {}
.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > * {}
.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > * .orbit-caption {}    
}
```

As well, here are two comparison pictures on [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/http://jsbin.com/aqejil/3)

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?  I'm sure it's probably a simple-enough fix but I can't seem to come up with a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a legitimate reason to be concerned about Opera versions released prior to 2011-12-06 (version history:  http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/)?

Comment: The page is for a university website, sadly they're picky about compatibility even with only 0.9% of page visitors being from Opera. lol  Edit: compatibility with Opera 11 and on is enough, to clarify

Comment: My question is not about Opera in general, but about specific versions.  Do you have enough users visiting the site with those versions to justify caring about them?  The only statistics I can find where they break Opera down by version lists 11.x as only .11%, which is smaller than what they list for *Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0* at .2% (source:  http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0)

Comment: Well only a fraction of 0.9% would be using earlier versions so I would say no there are not enough users in my own opinion. Compatibility with Opera11 has just been asked of me specifically(boss is an opera user/fan).  Also, Macs are only on Opera 12 so 11 was only one full version ago. And I just found that current versions of Opera Mini (ipad) exhibit the same activity.

Comment: I meant to say 11 is the 2nd to last version before webkit-based Opera 15